# How to dynamically translate an SVG group in D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, svg, bubble-chart

I'am working on a bubble-chart using d3. Now there should be an arrow as a graphical asset below the text elements. What I wan to achieve is a dynamic positioning of the arrow-group having a defined gap between itself and the last text:

[image]

I've already tried to position it with a percentage value:

`arr.append("g").attr("class", "arrow").style('transform', 'translate(-1%, 5%)');`

Which does not give the effect I want to.

I also tried to insert a dynamic value based on the radius of the circles which is simply not working and I don't know why:

`arr.append("g")
    .attr("class", "arrow")
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) { return "translate(20," + d.r / 2 + ")");});`

**OR**

`arr.append("g")
    .attr("class", "arrow")
    .style('transform', (d, i) => 'translate(0, ${d.r/2})');`

Please find my pen [here](https://codepen.io/Tyllionaire/pen/vqrrGr?editors=0010).

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. solved it! For everyone who is interested or having the same trouble:

My last attempt was nearly correct but I was not able to transform via `.style(...)`. I had to use `.attr(...)` like this:

`arr.append("g")
    .attr("class", "arrow")
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => translate(0, ${d.r/2})');`

Comment: If your solution fixed your problem, don't hesitate to accept your answer.